# Are "Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star" and "Itsy Bitsy Spider" the same song?

Tags: melody

I noticed when my baby sisters are listening to a certain melody, I start singing *Itsy Bitsy Spider* or *Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star*. This makes me wonder if they are the same melody with different lyrics.

Are they the same song?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear the piece of music that you're describing, because I cannot correlate the two melodies in my head.  Among other differences, Itsy Bitsy Spider is a swing rhythm, wheras Twinkle Twinkle Little Star is straight.  I cannot understand how they can be confused.  Please link to the melody that made you think of both songs, if possible.

Comment: Are you thinking of Twinkle and the Alphabet song?  Because those are the same, and IIRC are actually a melody by Mozart.

Comment: @Duston Mozart wrote a set of variations on that tune, but he did not write the tune.  He knew the tune as _Ah, vous dirais-je, maman,_ a French nursery song.  There is a link in the comments below, which I will repeat here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ah!_vous_dirai-je,_maman

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. They are both simple melodies, but they're different.

This is Twinkle - Twinkle Little Star:

[image]

This is The Itsy Bitsy Spider:

[image]

Comment: This question reminded me of something, so I went on a hunt... the movie Heartburn, 1986 - [Coming Around Again / Itsy Bitsy Spider - Carly Simon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9cidpLcPgA) I'd forgotten just how good a song that was.

Comment: On a related note, "Twinkle twinkle, little star" is basically the same melody as "Baa baa, black sheep", both of which are based on an 18th century French song: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ah!_vous_dirai-je,_maman

Comment: @GuyG as well as the alphabet / "ABC" song, at least the version I've always heard here in the US.

Comment: The melody is also often falsely attributed to Mozart. He did 12 variations on the French folk song Ah! Vouz dirai je maman (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ezvj-De6bxY) That said, it’s quite cool to listen to.

Comment: Not quite the same as the "ABC" song, the way I learned it. 'S' and 'X' would both be half notes, rather than two quarter notes. Admittedly, that's an extremely minor change.